# Python 3.6 - TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: typeerror, python-3.6

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Here is my program:

```
def power_of_n(power,n):  
    ans = n*n  
    for i in power:  
        ans = ans*n  
    return ans
```

Basically, I want to find the power of a number (power meaning squared or cubed).
My test case was `12 cubed == 1728` but it returned a TypeError.

Comment: Could you please format your code and what are you trying achieve?

Comment: Do you mean `for i in range(power):`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks glibdub!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better option would be use the builtin operator `**`

the solution to your specific issue is using range, as you are trying to iterate over an integer operator, in the interest of readability would flip the operators as well:

```
def power_of_n(n, power):  
ans = n*n  
for i in range(2,power):  
    ans = ans*n  
return ans
```

and your test case would be `power_of_n(2,3)==8`